# htaccess redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a domain **test.com**

Now i have the latest files in **test.com/backup/**

Now , what i need is, when i type **test.com** in browser it should go to **test.com/backup/**

How can i write code for that in **htaccess file**

Answer (score 9):

If you want it to be silent:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /backup/$1 [L,NC]
```

This will make **http://test.com/** appear to contain the files inside **/backup/** without having `backup` in the url

Answer (score 3):

in your .htaccess file:

Redirect 301 / /backup

Answer (score 0):

In index.php,

```
header('Location: /backup/');
exit;
```

Comment: Why would you have a file in your webroot that has the sole purpose of forwarding you to another page?  `.htaccess` solutions make more sense logically, and for SEO purposes.

Comment: Judging by his question (backups), I assume SEO is irrelevant here. Regardless, it makes no difference whether you use .htaccess or php to redirect; 301 or 302 status codes can be specified in both. I would agree with you if he only wants to mask the url, instead of redirect, that htaccess would definitely be the way to go.  However, since he says "go to", I assume he means redirect.  (Arguments about overhead between htaccess and php interpreter are outside the scope of this.  I'm simply saying the redirect can be performed equally in both.)

Answer (score 0):

Assum index.html exists and is your directoryindex.

redirectpermanent http://test.com/backup/

Answer (score 0):

In your .htaccess file put:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ backup [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.test.com/backup/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.test.com/backup/ [QSA,L]
```