# .htaccess redirection to subfolder (masked)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mask, subdirectory

I want to redirect "www.adomain.com" to "www.adomain.com/cms". The cms-part should be masked.

I don't get it to work silently. So "cms" is always part of the url.

I tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4475173/1052107, but I always get an Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /folder/$1
```

And this should go in the .htaccess file at the root of the domain.

This is pulled off a site I have doing this now, so it should work

Comment: This gives me an Internal Server Error.

Comment: @Pwdr Please check your Apache's error log for exact error description. There is not point in guessing what can be wrong here, as it could be few different things. It could be: 1) infinite redirect loop (with such rule it is very likely to be the case); 2) rewrite engine rules are not allowed to be placed in htaccess (configuration issue); 3) etc

Comment: Interesting... Do you have anything else specified in the htaccess file with regards to rewriting?

Comment: Try this one (should defeat infinite redirect, if that is the reason for server error): `RewriteRule ^(?!folder/)(.*)$ /folder/$1`

Comment: Thanks! This works: `RewriteRule ^(?!folder/)(.*)$ /folder/$1`

Comment: Same as above... it worked for me too: `RewriteRule ^(?!folder/)(.*)$ /folder/$1`