# htaccess redirect root to subfolder and mask the subfolder from the url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, root, subdirectory

I saw some posts but relating to this question and some even tried solving my problem but it did not work 100% for me

Now, I have a domain

```
 www.example.com
```

and all the huge content lies within a sub folder demo so I have to navigate

```
 http://www.example.com/demo
```

to view the content

What I need is I type in

http://www.example.com

and the content at the sub folder **/demo** should load up but it should mask the sub folder all the way, no matter how many times I hit the refresh page or navigate to some other page

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739623/htaccess-redirection-to-subfolder-masked) worked for me but when I clicked the logo at the home page which takes me to the index of my website, it unmasked the sub folder

Comment: Can you show us the code of the link?

Comment: [How to change the default main domain folder to subfolder](http://chanon-srithongsook.info/development-notes/change-main-domain-to-subfolder/)