# Masked redirect to subfolder using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mask, subdirectory

I have a new version of my website in a subfolder. What I am trying to do is redirect all traffic from "mysite.com.au" to "mysite.com.au/new-wp".
While doing this I Would like the url in the address bar to keep showing "mysite.com.au" and not "mysite.com.au/new-wp". 
I am also trying to make sure that all the pages under "mysite.com.au/new-wp" are served with the address bar showing "mysite.com.au/".
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739623/htaccess-redirection-to-subfolder-masked):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(?!new-wp/)(.*)$ /new-wp/$1
```

Now, I can see that when I type in "mysite.com.au" I get the page on "mysite.com.au/new-wp" and the url says "mysite.com.au". But for all other pages, I still see the "new-wp" in the url in the address bar. 
I would really appreciate it someone could point me the right direction.

Best regards,
Sarah

Answer (score 0):

As `$1` stands for first matched group the right one would be the second i.e. `$2`:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!new-wp/)(.*)$ /new-wp/$2
```

Comment: Thanks @Phellipe. I tried this. Unfortunately, I still do not see masking in the url for the other pages. I also tried the suggestion here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mask-all-traces-of-subdirectory-when-giving-wordpress-its-own-directory. No joy :(