# Joomla 3 Website 404 on every page

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla3.0

I have been searching around the web for a solution but can't seem to find any to fix this situation. I can access the website through *domain.com/joomla* but not on the main domain without the */joomla*.
(below are the two image to show the differences)

On my backend, the site is not offline, and I have at least 1 default article.

Could you please provide me with a new angle on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you've installed it in a subfolder, if you want to view the website via domain.com then install joomla in the domain root folder.

You can also try this: [.htaccess redirection to subfolder (masked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739623/htaccess-redirection-to-subfolder-masked)

Comment: for the above error, i went to reinstall the theme again, and everything went right. Of course, with your instructions to install at the domain root. Thanks man!