# Masked subfolder redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is driving me nuts... 
I have blah1.com and blah2.com on my server.

I need to do a masked redirect from blah1.com/BLAHFOLDER/file.php to blah2.com/BLAHFOLDER/file.php so that the url does not show blah2.com.

However, I do NOT want to redirect blah1.com/home.php... I only want to redirect the URLs that contain BLAHFOLDER.

There are many files in BLAHFOLDER that need to be redirected.

The closest answers I've gotten so far are these:
    [htaccess redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475129/htaccess-redirection?lq=1)
and 
    [.htaccess redirection to subfolder (masked)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739623/htaccess-redirection-to-subfolder-masked)

But I just could not get it to work with my setup.

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: "*...so that the url does not show blah2.com*". Can't keep `blah1.com` showing in the address bar because it is an external redirect. Maybe with a reverse proxy, but mod_proxy has to be enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you have both domains on two different hosts on the same server. If you have both domains on the same host, the answer from @AbsoluteƵERØ should work!

Try to put this in the .htaccess of the "blah1.com" host:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/FOLDER/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blah2.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This will redirect all files like blah1.com/FOLDER/file.php to blah2.com/FOLDER/file.php and so on. The other things, which are not in FOLDER, will not be redirected.

If you want, that the URL "blah1.com" always stays in the address bar and is not exchanged with blah2.com on redirect, enable mod_proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) on you server and exchange the "L" flag with the "P" flag, so your .htaccess on blah1.com will look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/FOLDER/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blah2.com/$1 [R,P]
```

Comment: Ok, got it to work perfectly, masked and all...
Haha, now I've got a new issue: blah1.com is not SSL, blah2.com IS ssl, and in the .htaccess file for blah2, I have 
    `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`
    `RewriteRule (.*) https://blah2.com%{REQUEST_URI}`
which messes up everything... Any ideas on how to fix this? When I remove these lines from the blah2 htacces, it works perfect.
SSL is NOT important from blah1.com.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check whether it's on the right domain or not:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blah1\.com
RewriteRule ^(BLAHFOLDER/file\.php) http://blah2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you're using two separate vhosts on the same physical host, then you can forgo the top line and make it just one rule to reside on `blah1.com`.

```
RewriteRule ^(BLAHFOLDER/file\.php) http://blah2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: But this will only work, if both domains are bound to the same host, or? From what the OP writes, I understand that this is not the case.

Comment: @M-z it would still work regardless, the only thing is if they're not on the same host and they run this file the `RewriteCond` is superfluous since that domain would match.

I took "on my server" to mean that they're likely either running a couple of vhosts or an alias, but regardless they're potentially showing the same code in both. Since they're not writing the logic into the app this was the safest solution I could give (with the info provided).

Comment: @AlbertCattan We were talking about vhosts not the "host" being the same box. If they were both under the same vhost then my solution would work as well. If they were separate vhosts then the top line in my rule would be extra since we wouldn't need to check it if the file is only showing under `blah1.com`.