# How can I 301 Redirect and Change Url with .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I just discovered that I have some duplicate pages that I need to remove but some pages that should not exist are indexed and generating small amounts of traffic.  I want to redirect those urls to the original ones.

http://www.example.com/buy-something.php

to

http://www.example.com/something.php

I basically need to remove the "buy-" in the urls and make sure the page is redirected to the proper page.  Here is what I have so far:

```
#301 Redirect buy- to none
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z\.]+).php$  /buy-$1.php  [L,R=301]
```

But this does nothing to the pages that should be redirected and adds a loop of buy-buy-buy-buy-buy-buy- to other pages and causes them to time out.  I have tried a few other variations but to no prevail.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [htaccess redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475129/htaccess-redirection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the syntax, right now you are redirecting any *.php to /buy-*.php,
since you want it the other way arround try:

```
RedirectRule ^buy-([a-zA-Z\.]+).php$  /$1.php  [L,R=301]
```

That should take any buy-*.php domains and redirect them to *.php with the Code 301.

Source:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is incorrect. It does the opposite to what you intended. Try this:

```
#301 Redirect buy- to none
RewriteRule ^buy-(.*).php$  /$1.php  [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what the issue was.